# tkinter Message works when run by itself, but when run from my main module it fails

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a tkinter application that opens a message widget and displays the content of some log files my main application makes. for some reason, this works when i run the extension which opens the window just by clicking it, or running it through command line, but when imported by my main module, i got the following error:
RuntimeError: Calling Tcl from different appartment

I tried simply pasting the code into the main module, but to the same effect. i really do not know what is going on. the code of the message is below.

```
from tkinter import *

def msg():
    error='Sorry, no logs available.'
    string=''
    win=Tk()
    win.title('Log')
    try:
        num=0
        a=open('C:\\ProgramData\\luck\\log.dat')
        lines=a.readlines()
        a.close()
    except:
        string=error
    while True:
        try:
            lines[num]=lines[num].replace('|',' ')
            lines[num]=lines[num].strip()
            lines[num]=lines[num]+'\n'
            num+=1
        except IndexError:
            break
    if string!=error:
        for line in lines:
            string+=line
    msg=Message(win, text=string)
    msg.config(bg='gray',font=('arabic',16,'normal'))
    msg.pack()
    mainloop()
msg()
```

i would put the code of the main module here, but it is pretty long.

Comment: You can only safely call `Tk()` once in a program.  You need to reuse the instance that your main module created rather than calling it again here.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will see if i can do that.

Comment: is it Ok to delete the Tk with the del keyword instead, it is a little difficult to reuse it, since i am using a simplified graphics module in my main method.

Comment: i am relativley new to python, just getting used to it.

Comment: `Tk()` is the object which represents your root window. Deleting it is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reorganize your code just a bit.

```
from tkinter import *

def msg(win):
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    # root.withdraw()  # uncomment after revision below
    msg(root)
```

If you import file, call `msg(root)` where `root` is the already created `Tk()` object.  Of course, adding the message object to your existing root window is probably not what you want.  So revise `msg` to create a new Toplevel containing the message.  Something like

```
    top = Toplevel(win)
    top.title('Log')
    ...
    msg = Message(top, text=string)
```

And uncomment `root.withdraw()` so you do not see the empty root window when you run the file directly.